# Why is code after await is not getting executed?

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

I am using a function requiring to be await. The code after this is not executed, but await function is obviously being executed as actions can be seen. But it is not clear to say if await function is really getting finished.

The specific case:
I am trying to connect my Discord-Bot to a voice channel using following command:

`vs = await message.author.voice.channel.connect()`

One can see that the bot is actually joining the channel. There are no errors occurring but a simple print statement afterwards is not being executed.

I would appreciate specific answers to discord.py rewrite but also tips why python's await statement could stop further code from being executed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`connect` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.Client.connect), calling `connect()` starts a loop:

> This is a loop that runs the entire event system and miscellaneous aspects of the library.

Moreover, it will only finish when the connection is terminated:

> Control is not resumed until the WebSocket connection is terminated.

The solution is to register event callbacks and use `connect()` in a new task, or can just use `connect()`/`client.run()` if your application doesn't need other tasks.